# /dev/mixer: Нет такого устройства или адреса

Tags: linux, c

Есть необходимость написать приложение считывающее звук с микрофона на Linux.
Приложение пишется на СИ.
ОС: Ubuntu 16.04 
Нашел хорошую статью на эту тему [работа со звуком в Linux](http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/mm/sound_borovski.html)
 
Написал и скомпилировал тестовый код.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/soundcard.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MIXER "/dev/mixer"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int mixer_fd, recmask, recsrc, vol;
  if ((mixer_fd = open(MIXER, O_RDWR)) == -1) {
    perror(MIXER);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  if (ioctl(mixer_fd, SOUND_MIXER_READ_RECMASK, &recmask) == -1) {
    printf("Микшер неактивен, попробуйте другое устройство");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  if ((recmask & SOUND_MASK_MIC) == 0 ) {
    printf("Запись с микрофона не поддерживается\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  ioctl(mixer_fd, SOUND_MIXER_READ_RECSRC, &recsrc);
  if ((recsrc & SOUND_MASK_MIC) == 0 ) {
    recsrc = SOUND_MASK_MIC;
    ioctl(mixer_fd, SOUND_MIXER_WRITE_RECSRC, &recsrc);
  }
  ioctl(mixer_fd, SOUND_MIXER_READ_MIC, &vol);
  if (vol < 90) vol+=10;
  ioctl(mixer_fd, SOUND_MIXER_WRITE_MIC, &vol);
  close(mixer_fd);
  return 0;
}
```

Но программа завершается с следующей ошибкой:

```
/dev/mixer: No such device or address
```

При этом файл `/dev/mixer` существует.

```
562 0 crw-rw---- 1 root audio 14, 48 мар 31 09:45 mixer3
561 0 crw-rw---- 1 root audio 14, 32 мар 31 09:45 mixer2
560 0 crw-rw---- 1 root audio 14, 16 мар 31 09:45 mixer1
176 0 crw-rw-rw- 1 root audio 14,  0 мар 31 09:45 mixer
```

Comment: попробуйте запустить с правами рута или добавьте себя в группу audio.

Comment: У меня тоже ОС: Ubuntu 16.04. Но никакого /dev/mixer не существует. Покажите вывод команды ls -l /dev/mixer*

Comment: @Sergey, и что теперь? Тут много вопросов возникает: от версии используемого ядра, до того, что в него вкомпилировано, плюс что делает user space (с чьей помощью эти устройства в каталоге были созданы).